# How to add disable attribute on component selector?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to disable button. But button is angular component. 
And Html5 disabled attribute cannot work on component selector.

I tried to add like this but does not work: `[attr.disabled]="isOpenModal`

Button Html code:

```
 <add-new-button [attr.disabled]="isOpenModal" 
                 (click)="openModal('new')"
                 class="nano-bc-green hover-effect">
 </add-new-button>
```

Button - Component "add new button"

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'nano-add-new-button',
    template: `
              <div class='nano-f-r nano-f'>
                    <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
                    <span class='nano-ml-5'>
                        Add New
                    </span>
              </div>`
})
export class NanoAddNewButtonComponent {
}
```

Open Modal method which is used on button:

```
public openModal(id: string): void {
        const data = {id: id};
        this.modalModel.add(AudienceModel.ENTITY_NAME, data);
}
```

Any idea for solution?

Comment: may be you can add a class to change opacity and with `pointer-events: none` ?

Comment: have you tried this? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: You can add an `@Input` in your component and bind it to the button you want to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the disabled logic into the click method itself:

Template:

```
 <add-new-button (click)="onModalClick()"
                 class="nano-bc-green hover-effect">
 </add-new-button>
```

TypeScript:

```
onModalClick() {
    if (!this.isOpenModal) {
      this.openModal('new');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I should set tu true "isOpenModal" in this case?

Comment: This work, but where I should put "isOpenModal = flase" ? 
Cus When I close the modal, then I can't open again this modal on addNew button. 
Cus isOpenModal stay on true:
 public onModalClick() {
            if (!this.isOpenModal) {
                this.openModal('new');
                this.isOpenModal = true;
            }
    }

Answer (score 4):

Because your `add-new-button` component can be anything, and `disabled` is not a property that all elements have, that can't work.
Check out the list of [Global Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).

You have to define your own `disabled` property:

```
@Input() disabled: boolean;
```

And you can bind this to the elements you want to disable like:

```
<button [disabled]="disabled">My button</button>
```

You can use it like this after:

```
 <add-new-button [disabled]="isOpenModal"
             (click)="openModal('new')"
             class="nano-bc-green hover-effect">
 </add-new-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is disable attribute

```
<my-date-picker [options]="myOptions" [disabled]="disabled" 
                (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"></my-date-picker>
```

it may be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS selector `[ng-reflect-disabled]` to trigger the disabled value.

and add `[disabled]="isOpenModal"` instead of `[attr.disabled]="isOpenModal"` in your HTML file.

and in your CSS file add the below code:

```
add-new-button[ng-reflect-disabled="true"] {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you shouldn't use any `ng-reflect-...` selector as they are only for debugging purposes